# VSCode Autocomplete And Suggestion (IntelliSense) Doesn't Work For Tensorflow And Keras Libraries?

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, keras

The VSCode autocomplete option doesn't work for tensorflow and keras libraries; However i've installed python and pylance extension on it; is there any solution to make it work or not, without install new extension or something like as AI autocomplete; Kite and tabinine?

For instance, here i'm trying to use layers or preprocessing from keras API but it doesn't show anything at all

[image: Load Keras Preprocessing]
[image: Load Keras Layers]

Also notice here the tensorflow version and python version

[image]

Comment: You could try copilot https://github.com/features/copilot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### A potentially useful fix:

> try adding this to the bottom of your `tensorflow/__init__.py`
>
> ```
> # Explicitly import lazy-loaded modules to support autocompletion.
> # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
> if _typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
>  from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v2 import estimator as estimator
>  from keras.api._v2 import keras
>  from keras.api._v2.keras import losses
>  from keras.api._v2.keras import metrics
>  from keras.api._v2.keras import optimizers
>  from keras.api._v2.keras import initializers
> # pylint: enable=g-import-not-at-top
> ```

- Find the location of the `tensorflow` package and open the `__init__.py` file in the `tensorflow` folder

  [image]
- Add the above codes at the bottom of the file

  [image]
- It should be noted that it will be useful to import in the following way

  ```
  import tensorflow as tf

  tf.keras
  ```

  [image]

  [image]
- Importing in the previous way still can't get intellisense

  [image]

  [image]

Comment: The [new version](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.10.0) of `tensorflow` has some updates. Still need to use the import format from the answer though (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTbKt.png)).

Comment: Unfortunately. the fix is not working for me with TensorFlow 2.9.1 and VS Code 1.73.1 with python extension v2022.18.2. I am using Anaconda3 and adapted the file in the path "...\Anaconda3\pkgs\tensorflow-base-2.9.1-mkl_py39h6a7f48e_1\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow". I am quite sure this is where the change needs to happen.

Any ideas, what else could be done? Lucky me, this is my first contact with VS Code and I need Tensorflow for taking part in a workshop. Didn't work with python for a few years either. Such an error makes a really nice comeback -.-